# Always returning true if the stack contains different values

Tags: c#, arrays, stack, c#-code-model

I am trying to compare two stacks and returns true if they are same, and if they are false return false. But this function always returns false.

```
public bool Check_Winner()
{
    int[] tower3Array = ui.tower3.ToArray();
    int[] tower4Array = ui.tower4.ToArray();

    if (tower3Array.Length != tower4Array.Length)
    {
         return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tower3Array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (tower3Array[i] != tower4Array[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please give some example data where you expect `true` but get `false`?

Comment: Please post a [mre] with a `main` that calls the method with a specific input that does not yield the result you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Check if the stacks have the same elements in the same order using their arrays. If the arrays have different lengths, return false. Otherwise, check each element and return false if they don't match. Use debug statements or breakpoints to verify the stack data and the Stack. Capacity property to check their capacity.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @KlausGütter why? Comments are intended for asking for more information about the question, or for suggesting improvements for the question, not for answering the question.